# Mac reports different versions of Java in command terminal and System Preferences

Tags: java, macos, version

On my Mac the Java version indicated in a command terminal is 1.7.0_40. The Java
control panel (System Preferences) indicates 1.7.0_51.

Why are they different?

Some additional information:

From the command terminal, `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` responds with:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    1.7.0_40,         x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386:     "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

`JAVA_HOME` is set to:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
```

From the command terminal, `java -version` responds with:

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

Comment: My guess is that auto-updates are somehow not updating the version information. I saw the same issue you did (version stuck at u51 even though I had u60); after uninstalling the JDK and manually reinstalling it through Oracle's installer, I see the correct version.

Comment: I currently have a similar situation: the panel says 1.8.0_71 and java_home says 1.8.0_51. The path for the panel is `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java` whereas `java_home` points to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home`. And, `java -version` points to 51. Very confusing.

Comment: And, after updating with a new JDK installer (to 72), all but the plugin Java seem to bump up in version.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624667/mac-osx-java-terminal-version-incorrect

Answer (score -1):

When you run the command line java it is running the one configured in your system bin path.

The other one in system preferences must be being picked up from a different location elsewhere in your system.

Comment: I am seeing the same discrepancy, but I definitely have only one JDK installed on my system.