# Mac says java is updated but terminal disagrees

Tags: java, macos, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just downloaded Java 7 for my Mac OS X through Oracle's site. When I go to System Preferences>Java>Java Control Panel>Update  -- The control panel says that I'm updated and have Java 7 installed(also the Update Now button is disabled). Then if I open terminal and type "java -version" it lists that I have 'java version "1.6.0_65"' What's going on here? I need to have Java 7 because Oracle SQLDeveloper will not run correctly without it, at least that's what the program start message says.(Haven't actually tried SQLDev on my current Java 1.6)

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624667/mac-osx-java-terminal-version-incorrect) (I googled _"terminal wrong java version"_. There were more hits. Something there might help)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) in the System Preferences you're seeing.

You'll  want to install the Java SE Development Kit (JDK) and install it:

> **[JDK 1.7.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)** • jdk-7u51-macosx-x64.dmg
>
> **[JDK 1.8.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)** • jdk-8-macosx-x64.dmg

They don't exactly make it clear that [what is here](http://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp?locale=en), is not that same as [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).