# Can't run SikuliX scripts from Command Line (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, automation, sikuli

I'm using MacOS 10.11.6. According to the instructions [here](http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basicinfo.html#sikulix-on-mac), I should have a command `runsikulix` available, but I don't. (Should it be available after installing?  Or do I need to set the variable myself?  I couldn't find any explanation).   So I tried the following, hoping it would work:

I wrote a SikuliX script that works when running from the IDE, and tried running it with the command line as follows:

```
open ./Applications/SikuliX.app -r ./agilent/test.sikuli
```

and I got this response:

```
open: invalid option -- r
```

Without the file argument, the IDE opens.  Can anyone give me a pointer on how to run a file?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just worked for me in the Terminal (Note that I have the Sikuli app in its own folder inside the Applications folder):

```
java -jar /Applications/Sikuli/SikuliX.app/Contents/Java/sikulix.jar -r '/Applications/Sikuli/Sikuli_Stuff/test1-about.sikuli/'
```

[EDIT on May 11, 2020]

The path to the java JRE can get frustratingly obtuse in OSX. I recently was beset by "Unsupported major.minor version" errors when using the old java path, so I had to track down the newer runtime environment binary, which is now in

`/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`

So in order to make this work (again), I had to specify the path to this newer JRE. The new command line looks like:

```
/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar /Applications/Sikuli/SikuliX.app/Contents/Java/sikulix.jar -r '/Applications/Sikuli/Sikuli_Stuff/test1-about.sikuli/'
```

And one may `alias` a link to this new RE as described in [Mac OSX Java Terminal version incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624667/mac-osx-java-terminal-version-incorrect)