# SonerQube doesnt start

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, java-11

Sonarqube Startup script does not start ob ubuntu 16.04

Error log shows:

```
Encountered an error running main: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube requires Java 11+ to run
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube requires Java 11+ to run
    at org.sonar.application.App.checkJavaVersion(App.java:93)
    at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:56)
    at org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Startup failed: Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM.
JVM did not exit on request, terminated
JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

If i run java -version:

```
java version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Comment: can you rule this out ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624667/mac-osx-java-terminal-version-incorrect

Comment: cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"

Answer (score 11):

1. Open `conf/wrapper.conf` file
2. Change `wrapper.java.command=java` to path where your JavaDK is installed eg. `wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4\bin\java`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem a few moments ago, my `JAVA_HOME` variable pointed to the correct version of my profile, but when I run `java -version`, it printed `1.8`, so I run this command:

```
update-java-alternatives -l
```

This showed me all Java versions that were installed on my machine.
After that, I run this another command:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-11-oracle
```

This changed the Java version on my machine and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

"Warning Support for Java 8 has been deprecated in SonarQube v7.8 and will be removed in SonarQube v7.9 LTS."

checkout you java -version, and the Supported Platforms requirements: https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.7/requirements/requirements/

Then go to the downloads and choose what is the best for you: 
https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/ (Show all versions)

Answer (score 0):

Check for the JRE version, I have come across the issue where the Java SDK version and JRE -version was different. That may be the issue.

Comment: No JRE since version 11

Answer (score 0):

Most user would like to download JDK 11 here as mentioned in recent comments. That should works.

However, I would recommend to install latest version from following link (because you have just downloaded latest sonarqube) for better compatibility.

SDK download link: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

FYI, 
For mac user,
Install JVM on your machine (I installed it by Homebrew).

> brew cask install java

and restarted the sonar by

> ./sonar.sh restart

it worked for me